# Ни хорошо Ни плохо / Не хорошо Не плохо

Tags: орфография, не-или-ни

Когда пишется НЕ, а когда НИ? Исправьте ошибки, если есть. Может, запятые поставить где нужно? Или НЕ - написать слитно?

1) Мне ни хорошо ни плохо.

2) Мне не хорошо и не плохо.

3) Вася сделал свою работу ни хорошо ни плохо.

4) Коля  водил машину  не хорошо и не плохо.

5) Петя научился работать на компьютере и не хорошо и не плохо.

Answer (score 3):

1) Мне ни хорошо ни плохо (устойчивое выражение, слова категории состояния, союз НИ...НИ, усиление отрицания)

2) Мне не хорошо и не плохо (отрицание двух противоположных признаков, слова категории состояния, союз И)

3) Вася сделал свою работу ни хорошо ни плохо (устойчивое выражение,  союз НИ...НИ, усиление отрицания, обстоятельства)

4) Коля водил машину не хорошо и не плохо (отрицание двух противоположных признаков, обстоятельства, союз И)

5) Петя научился работать на компьютере и не хорошо, и не плохо (отрицание двух противоположных признаков, обстоятельства, союз И...И)